# CS:GO - Recognize party members during a match

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Is there a way to easily recognize party members during a match? I do not mean team members, but members I started a group with ingame. It's hard to spot them visually amongst the other team members, so it would be nice to either be able to always show player names, without pointing on them, or otherwise highlight group members.
Is anything possible in this regard?

Comment: not sure if this helps, but the radar has a specific color for each teammate. you could check the radar for the colors assigned to your friends.

Comment: my radar has no different colors, just all the same for one team.

Comment: unfortunately this only works for competitive play. casual play enforces uniform colors.

Comment: As mentioned prior - if you are on competitive mode this is possible (kinda. a unique colour for each player, purple, blue, green, yellow or orange) but it doesnt differentiate between players and friends. And of course it only works in one game mode.

Comment: They really need to do something about that. I too have been having problems with that when I play with my friends. It is very annoying to have to call out where you are on the map just to meet up and feel like youre really playing with a friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the game doesn't have any support for showing party members in any special way during matches. If they are on your friends list they will show up when you <kbd>shift</kbd> - <kbd>tab</kbd> as friends in the server, but not specially in the game itself.